# how do i separate css, javascript, images for admin side and visitor side in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am very new to ruby on rails, i am confused with css and java-script file include method in ruby on rails.
when i am using below code for file include in visitor side it will includes all css and javascript files on every page including admins css and javascript also.

```
<head>
    <title>Content management system</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

when i view source of html file it will look like this

```
<head>
    <title>Content management system</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/admin/colorbox.self-c93dd376833c0e267b594921dd5498fcbb3f446331a35dc75372b26fd8c61167.css?body=1" data-turbolinks="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/bootstrap.min.self-be6a645f213f356601ff235da5760f5080076f6168dec3d19d33587edbf75b95.css?body=1" data-turbolinks="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" data-turbolinks="true" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-167adc1826a31cef2040f73c4d3996900974f3b4578f72e2c1bfb814d66ca2fb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.self-f2d64b74536a49f843b022431e37325973468a71c9b362343deb0b6c582e5ba0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" data-turbolinks="true"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="Y+tOunCBKVwpv7hfpg2+OFA7XBQTjldPTMRb3SC8DHUkUfrOfxkMBYiFLwGPSVAJiCzS21WsFtY179tcsa9I9A==" />
</head>
```

i wanted only specific css and javascript files should be included even in visitor side.

**folder structure**
this is just an example structure

```
app
-assets
 -fonts
 -mages
  -admin
    -1.jpg
    -2.jpg
  -visitors
     -3.jpg
     -4.jpg 
 -javascripts
  -1.js
  -2.js
  -admin
    -3.js 
 -stylesheets
   -1.css
   -2.css
   -admin
    -3.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code example `application.js` and `application.css` are manifest files used by the asset pipeline to declare what gets loaded when you call `stylesheet_link_tag` or `javascript_include_tag` from within your view.

However, the `application` filename is just what's used as the default manifest name by Rails. You can change this to whatever you want as long as it matches what's called from `stylesheet_link_tag` or `javascript_include_tag`. So, to isolate what specific assets get loaded in your admin and main site, all you need to do is break `application.js` and `application.css` into separate files, each being loaded within that respective domain of your site.

You may also need to add the new manifest files to be loaded by the asset pipeline as well:

```
config.assets.precompile << 'app/assets/javascripts/admin.js'
config.assets.precompile << 'app/assets/stylesheets/admin.scss.css'
```

The definitions within your app would look something like this:

**app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb**

```
<head>
    <title>Content management system</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'admin', 'data-turbolinks' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

**app/controllers/admin_controller.rb**

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
   layout 'layouts/admin'

   # ...
end


app
-assets
 -fonts
 -mages
  -admin
    -1.jpg
    -2.jpg
  -visitors
     -3.jpg
     -4.jpg 
 -javascripts
  -1.js
  -2.js
   admin.js <-- included by admin.html.erb layout
  -admin
    -3.js 
 -stylesheets
   -1.css
   -2.css
   admin.css <-- Also included by admin.html.erb
   -admin
    -3.css
```

Then define admin.scss.css and admin.js just as you would your application manifest:

**admin.js**

```
 *= require_tree './admin'
```

Comment: using your solution admin side problem is resolved,but at visitor side still all admin resources is loading i mean all css and javascript is also loading in visitor side

Comment: is there any way to include all files manually because in some .html.erb file some unnecessary files also loaded how can i remove that using this method?

Comment: Per your first question just remove assets you don't need from the visitor-side `application.js` or whatever the equivalent is. You can include individual files manually the same way. Just use `javascript_include_tag 'my_file.js'`, though you should just remove files from the manifest files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the assets in each individual file you want it to work.

In **erb** files:

`<%= stylesheet_include_tag 'your_css_file.css' %>`

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'your_js_file.js' %>`

In **haml** files:

`= stylesheet_link_tag 'your_css_file.css'`

`= javascript_include_tag 'your_js_file.js'`

In your **application.html.erb** file (using conditionals):

```
<!-- Only load the assets when in contacts view -->
<% if current_page?(contacts_path) %>
  <%= stylesheet_include_tag 'your_css_file.css' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'your_js_file.js' %>
<% end %>
```